# Trouble with Session on Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've a problem with session on code igniter. First, i want to build an advance search function. The advance search function will allow user to search using several category. After the user search something and the result successfully return, on the left sidebar will show the search key and an "edit button". The edit button will allow user to go to the previous page and change their search key. That's why, i need to use session to store the search key. But after i set the session and try to retrieve the value, a problem has occurred.

This is the workflow.
- Set the session on a.php
- Get the session value within a function on b.php
- Ajax to b.php to receive the session value and show it.

For information, i use php and code igniter for the server side.

This is the code:

a.php

```
    if (!empty($params['modelname'])){
        $modelid = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($params['modelname']); $i++)
        {
            $modelid .= $params['modelname'][$i];
                if($i+1 < count($params['modelname']))
                {
                    $modelid .= ", ";
                }
        }
        $data = array(
            "modelname" => $modelid  
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
     ?>
     <span id="model"><strong><?php echo $modelid; ?><?php echo form_button('btnsearchmodel', 'Edit','class="btnsearchkata" id="btnsearchmodel"')?></strong></span>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <?php }
```

---

b.php

```
public function getselectedmodel()
{
    $data = $this->session->userdata('modelname');
    echo $data;
}
```

---

c.php

```
function getCariModel()
   {
        var brandname = ""
        $(".brand").each(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked') ){
                brandname += $(this).val()+',';                    
            }
        });

        if(brandname != "")
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: '<?php echo site_url("ajax_data/getselectedmodel"); ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {c: "ambilmodel"},
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
   }
```

---

The problem is: when I didn't receive the data. And when I try to alert the data, the alert didn't work at all. It seems like the request is not success

I guess the problem is when i set the session. but i really don't know what is wrong with my code. anyone could help me? Thank you

Comment: `a problem has occurred.` What problem exactly?

Comment: i couldn't receive the data, when i try to alert the data, the alert didn't work, it seems like the ajax is not success.

Comment: why don't you use session data directly in ajax controller insted of posting from javascript?

Comment: i've try it, but it need to refresh the page to update the session value. For example, the session value has updated, then when i try to show it, the value will be the old data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are waiting JSON in javascript, but in your controller action `getselectedmodel` you do not have [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode). Try this:

```
public function getselectedmodel()
{
    $data = $this->session->userdata('modelname');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
}
```

If you still have no output. Try going directly to action you are requesting and update your question.